# How to create an android web app where updation of apk is not required and will work offline too?

Tags: android, html, webview

I want to build an android web app where i don't need to provide the user with an update of the apk.

I did achieve this by using WebView. But i also want the apk to work offline if there is no internet connectivity after the app has been used atleast once by the user. And on detection of connectivity load the webpages again from the URL provided in the webview.

How can i make a webapp work offline in an android apk??

How do i achieve this?? Please help! Thanks in Advance

Comment: Shivani, webapp and offline? Didn't get your question, can you please ellaborate more?

Comment: @pratik I mean through webview i can load a website in my apk and the user feels as if he is using a native android app which works only with internet connection. So along with is functionality.. is it possible that if the user does not have internet he can still view the webpages through some cache process or something??

Comment: Yes you can do this, first time just save your data to database or in file. And then use it second time and further, this is the only solution.

Comment: I recently answered a similar question. Check this out - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26213441/is-it-possible-that-a-apk-file-be-run-without-wifi/26214305#26214305

Answer (score 0):

You can save all information (text) to database, images, css, js or other files to file storage and populate it on app launch. Then you can have offline mode and use app without internet.

And if you got all information you can use not only webview but all other android items- listview, buttons...